# Using Eclipse + PyDev + python2.7 on windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, odoo

I am new to openERP, 
I have installed openERP 6.0 version,python 2.7.2,Eclipse Juno and windows XP. I am following the developer book module structure on pydev.

while importing module osv compiler saying that unsolved import. Now I am getting the question like

Does python2.7 work for openERP 6.0 on Windows?

I have externally supplied the library.zip for interpreter Python.

Please provide me the steps to install and configure on pydev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You need to have Python 2 (2.5 or later for OpenERP v6.0, 2.6 or 2.7 for v6.1)" http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/install/linux/server/index.html

So it should work fine with 2.7. Did you install using the Windows "All-In-One Installation"? Then it should install everything for you (it uses its own python dll on Windows). Does openERP work correctly? Is it just your module that's not working? Need more details to be able to help with that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It is clearly mentioned for linux but not for windows, I downloaded and installed 6.1 version of openERP. in library of openerp server/client/web only I could fin the python 2.6 dll not 2.7